# user address schema for neo4j

Tags: neo4j, database-schema

Should address node properties be further divided into

`city{name,postcode}`
`state{name,code}` and
`coordinates {lat,long}`

Would it make search user by lat/long, state, country faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a separate property for each component (e.g., state) of an address will make searching by a component much faster, as you would not need to use a [regexp](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#query-where-regex) to search for the nodes with a specific component value (which is slow and difficult to program), and you can take advantage of [indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html) to quickly get the nodes of interest.